# Google Analytics Tag for Dev vs. Prod

Tags: google-analytics

I run a standard google analytics tracking code (ga.js asynch version) on a website. 
I am wondering if there is a line of js I can add to the tracking code so that I can segregate dev/prod data?  e.g. when I pull in the codebase to do dev work, I can set the tag to DEV. When releasing back to production, DEV tag gets replaced with PROD tag.

Is this even possible and if so, how do i implement it?

One method I thought of is just to create a new "property" (which would generate a new ua number, which I could add during dev. that would allow me to track it all separately.)

Wondering if there are any other methods I should consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not worried about collecting data from my development server, but I do want to make sure I'm not polluting my production data -- I've been using some variation of the following:

```
if (!/devServer|localhost/.test(window.location.hostname))
{
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-11111111-1']);
}
```

On the devserver domain (or on localhost), `_setAccount` doesn't get executed, so the tracker defaults to the default tracker, `UA-99999999-1`. This allows you to still see tracking data being sent to the analytics servers (via ga_debug.js, chrome dev tools, firebug, fiddler, etc), but doesn't register against your production profiles.

Downsides -- it is an extra bit of code that get's run on the client.

If you do want analytics from your development servers, you could try something like:

```
gaq.push(
    [ '_setAccount', 
      /devServer|localhost/.test(window.location.hostname) ? 'UA-11111111-1', 
    'UA-22222222-1']
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to mike's answer is to setup a filter in your profile based on the url or domain or based off any number of other things.