# How to catch 'ga is not defined' in your dev environments

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So I have my development environment, and every time I run the project, I have a javascript error in my console:

`ga is undefined`

Of course I am not at the correct domain so Google Analytics see this as an issue and I am fine with that, but it doesn't allow the rest of my Javascript to run so I have modals and other JS based functionality that stops working.

My thought were I could just write a wrapper method and check for ga undefined. But before I do that I just wanted to see if there was a better solution or possibly different way of thinking about my setup.

Cheers,

Devin

Comment: I don't understand why the symbol is undefined in the first place. However, testing it before using it is pretty much all you can do.

Comment: How/where are you including the tag?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274803/uncaught-referenceerror-ga-is-not-defined) that may help you

Comment: I've worked on code bases that do exactly this;  it seemed to work just fine. There was some `analytics.js` file that provided a stub if `ga` wasn't actually loaded on the page.

Comment: Oh you mean like if ga was undefinded I would have a backup ga object to take over?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with a method of redefining `ga` rather than trying to catch the error. In the backend we had logic to only included the Google Analytics script tag if the host url included our domain so when it was localhost or a dev url the script was not included.

So as a resolution I took the answer from this SO question ( [Google Analytics Tag for Dev vs. Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295311/google-analytics-tag-for-dev-vs-prod) ) and implemented a similar solution in the backend instead and excluded the following code when not our production website domain.

`ga('create', 'UA-********-1', 'mywebsite.com');`

The result, `ga` was still defined but does not send data to our Google Analytics account.

Good Luck,

Devin